# Encrypt internet traffic with ssh

Tags: ssh, encryption, cygwin, browsing

#### Purpose:

I want to encrypt my browsing. According to [this lifehacker article](https://lifehacker.com/237227/geek-to-live--encrypt-your-web-browsing-session-with-an-ssh-socks-proxy) it can be done by setting up OpenSSH on Windows with Cygwin.

#### What I don't understand is:

If I install the server on my computer and start it, and then connect to it from the same computer; will my browsing be encrypted?

If not, do I need to run the ssh server on a separate computer, which I then connect to?
I don't want to connect to a different computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that if you are at an untrusted location, e.g. free public WiFi, you can open up an encrypted channel to your home server (you must thus have an online computer at home) and relay all traffic through that. This will make sure that no one at the public WiFi place can get any information about your browsing (except that you contact your home server).

It would be pointless to set this up to relay traffic *from* your local computer *to* your local computer. Nothing will be hidden, complexity is added.

Answer (score 0):

SSH is pointless without another machine to connect to.

Comment: Ok. So it does not work this way.